# Why can't I use addition like this in foreach?

Tags: javascript

Javascript's foreach equivalent:

```
for ( var i in products )
{
    document.write("Write" + i + 1 );
}
```

Output:

```
Write01
```

**Edit:**
I tried parsing `i` into an integer.

```
for ( var i in products )
{
    document.write("Write" + parseInt(i) + 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `i` is a number, but gets cast to a string by the first `+`. Use this:

```
for ( var i in products ) {
  document.write(""); document.write("Write" + (i + 1) );
  // ------------------------------------------^
}
```

Comment: Thanks! STH had the same answer but you had an explanation.

Comment: +1 <offtopic>I think he is, but I guess it could be taken either way. </offtopic>

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). As shown in that table, the + operator associates left-to-right.

So:

```
a + b + c
```

Is grouped as follows:

```
((a + b) + c)
```

So in your original code, the expression is grouped as follow:

```
("Write" + i) + 1
```

In other words, it's a string concatenation followed by another string concatenation. Since you intend to do the arithmetic addition (i + 1) first, you'd have to group them explicitly:

```
"Write" + (i + 1)
```